# How to display URLs from an HTML string in Angular Dart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to get Angular Dart to display a link in a  tag from an HTML string.

At first, I tried to just set the inner HTML of the container to be the HTML string, but that didn't work, so I then I tried to use Dart's `DomSanitizationService` class, but that also doesn't seem to work.

What I have so far is

Dart:

```dart
class SomeComponent {
    final DomSanitizationService sanitizer;
    SafeUrl some_url;
    SomeComponent(this.sanitizer) {
          some_url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('https://www.google.com');
    }

    String html_string = '''
    <a [href]="some_url">Hi</a>
    ''';

    String get Text => html_string;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div [innerHTML]="Text"></div>
```

The error I'm getting is `Removing disallowed attribute <A [href]="some_url">`. The text `Hi` seems to show, but there is no link anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you bypassed URL sanitanization, you have to bypass HTML sanitanization as well using `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` to return markup.
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml